# smart page resizing

Tags: html, css, positioning

Suppose I have an HTML page with three blocks of fixed width (their height can vary if that's important), like shown on picture:
[image]

I would like to make it behave as shown on next picture: when browser screen width is reduced so it can't fit all three blocks in one line, first block goes down.
[image]

Is it possible to achieve such behavior? Preferably with CSS only but any working solution would be great.

Comment: This is the default behavior of the web-browsers.

Comment: @HotTester: No it´s not. If a user was to make their UA more narrow BLOCK 3 would jump down, not BLOCK 1. Using float: left acts like a que, last in (the code), first to jump down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: red; width: 200px;">DIV2</div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: yellow; width: 200px;">DIV3</div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; float: left; background-color: lightBlue; width: 200px;">DIV1</div>
    <br style="clear: left;">
</div>
```

This one works. You put block 1 as the last one and only make that one float left.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like exactly what I need. Puts first block on bottom by default in Opera 10.10 while working fine in all other browsers which is quite acceptable.

Comment: Nice one, although it only works consistently for the first block and is hardly compatible with IE.

Comment: @deceze: Just checked it, in IE all the blocks are indeed positioned in a single row. But still I suppose this works for me since blocks 2 and 3 can be wrapped in a single DIV thus making them to be positioned inline.

Answer (score 2):

It's virtually impossible to let the *first* block drop down without any Javascript trickery. Making the right-most one drop with `float: left` is easy on the other hand.

Comment: +1 for being the only answer thus-far that caught the fact that block 1 was supposed to drop

Comment: I just wish I had a better answer to provide, but this seems to call for a lot of custom Javascripting.

Answer (score 0):

Use divs with float:left and fixed width values

```
        <div style="float:right; width:250px; position:relative; height:100px; border:solid 1px #000000">    
3
    </div>        
        <div style="float:right; width:250px; position:relative; height:100px; border:solid 1px #000000">
        2    
    </div>
<div style="float:right; width:250px; position:relative; height:100px; border:solid 1px #000000">    
        1
    </div>
```

like so...
I am aware that the 1st one will go right but this is the simplest i can do without getting into javascript..

Comment: That would make block 3 drop to the next line, not block 1

Comment: Re Revision: This *would* make block 1 drop, but not in the way the OP requested. Block 1 would float to the right, not the left.

Comment: @deceze: Yeah, I'd thought about using `float:right` myself and rejected it for just that reason.  Like you, I don't really see any obvious way to do this with CSS alone, so I'm unfortunately reduced to pointing out flaws in other people's answers.

Answer (score -1):

Put all these three blocks inside a div and set it's width to 100%, when the screen will resize the blocks will be arranged automatically.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
  <div style="width: 50px; float left;">DIV1</div>
  <div style="width: 50px; float left;">DIV2</div>
  <div style="width: 50px; float left;">DIV3</div>
  <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>
```

Comment: That would make block 3 drop to the next line, not block 1